# Kerberos service started with Error: Cannot open DB2 database on Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, kerberos

I installed kerberos on Ubuntu 18 with `sudo apt install krb5-kdc krb5-admin-server`

But, When I ran `systemctl status krb5-kdc.service`, it turns out:

```
Feb 17 21:25:23 device2 krb5kdc[8675]: Cannot open DB2 database '/var/lib/krb5kdc/principal': No such file or directory - while initializing database for realm DENNIS.COM
Feb 17 21:25:23 device2 krb5kdc[8675]: krb5kdc: cannot initialize realm DENNIS.COM - see log file for details
Feb 17 21:25:23 device2 systemd[1]: krb5-kdc.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 17 21:25:23 device2 systemd[1]: krb5-kdc.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 17 21:25:23 device2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Kerberos 5 Key Distribution Center.
```

I have set the realm with `kdb5_util create -r DENNIS.COM -s`

```
[realms]
    DENNIS.COM = { 
        kdc = device2
        admin_server = device2
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

solved the problem with the following steps:

```
1. sudo kdb5_util create -r DENNIS.COM -s
2. set a password.
3. check if there is /var/lib/krb5kdc/principal existed.
4. Then sudo service krb5-kdc restart.
```